# Generator Expression must be parenthesized error

Tags: python, github

The brute force library of python(https://github.com/rdegges/brute)

```
*brute.py*
# ...
return (
    ''.join(candidate) for candidate in
    chain.from_iterable(
        product(
            choices,
            repeat = i,
        ) for i in range(start_length if ramp else length, length + 1),
    )
)
```

Exception

```
File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\brute.py", line 68
product(
^
SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the comma at the end of the last `for loop`.
`for i in range(start_length if ramp else length, length + 1),` -> this comma

```
>>> x = 5,
>>> x
(5,)
>>>
```

Putting a comma after a variable evaluates to a tuple of one element.
`chain.from_iterable` expects the first argument to be a generator not a tuple.

Because of that comma, your code actually evaluates to
`chain.from_iterable((product(choices, repeat = i) for i in range(start_length if ramp else length, length + 1)))`
instead of
`chain.from_iterable(product(choices, repeat = i) for i in range(start_length if ramp else length, length + 1))`

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in tabulations. See this contribution:

https://github.com/rdegges/brute/pull/9/commits/86fb09476cca2146764b0aae6b5ab9c6e0c7292b

Regards